# vim indentation setup - Ruby

Tags: vimrc, indentation

I have a problem with indentation using vim.

Lets say I have a file:

```
class My
end // <-- cursor is here
```

When I press O vim will create new line in between **class** and **end** and it will be indented. When I add a method def to it so the file looks like this:

```
class My
  def my
  end
end
```

Vim inserts tab for the automatic indentation not spaces so in git diff it looks like this:

```
class My
    def my
    def
end
```

My .vimrc is very basic:

```
set nocompatible
filetype off
let mapleader = "\<space>"
set tabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 expandtab " setting up tab behaviour
set number " show line numbers
set relativenumber " make the line numbers relative

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Plugin 'ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim'
Plugin 'thoughtbot/vim-rspec'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-surround'
Plugin 'vim-ruby/vim-ruby'

call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required

map <Leader>t :call RunCurrentSpecFile()<CR>
map <Leader>s :call RunNearestSpec()<CR>
map <Leader>l :call RunLastSpec()<CR>
map <Leader>a :call RunAllSpecs()<CR>
nmap 0 ^
nmap <leader>vr :tabe $MYVIMRC<cr>
nmap <leader>so :source $MYVIMRC<cr>
nmap <leader>cs :tabe db/schema.rb<cr>
imap jk <esc>
imap kj <esc>

syntax on
```

Any idea on how to fix this so the automatic indention is two spaces? 
It drives my **nuts!** I have to spend so much time fixing indentation after every commit....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to use two spaces instead of tab, try

```
set shiftwidth=2
set tabstop=2
set expandtab
```

More on this here on [wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Converting_tabs_to_spaces) or in help

```
:h shiftwidth
:h tabstop
:h expandtab
```

Comment: Yes but it is there on line 4 of .vimrc - **set tabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 expandtab**

Comment: I am sorry I missed it.

Comment: np, it is wird. shiftwith should be responsible for autoindent and expandtab should convert tabs to spaces..

Comment: crap - it is working now.... I think I didn't source the .vimrc after adding expandtab